# How can I make attribute, which will manage an access to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, attributes

everyone. I have met the problem. What from should my attribute's class be derived and what method should I override, if I want to make an attribute, which will manage an access to controller for users.
I've already made the attribute, that inherits AuthorizeAttribute. It works fine, but I got an opinion that this way is wrong.
Please, show me right example of such attribute :)

Comment: Attributes are not magical. By themselves they do nothing, they're depending on some other piece of code to discover the attributes and use them. As such, any code that goes looking for the AuthorizeAttribute might not expect your attribute nor know how to handle it. However, I'm not well versed in web development so I'll defer that part to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer to my question. For solve this problem you should use ActionFilterAttribute

Links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters